# "ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/utserver’: File exists" error while installing µTorrent

Tags: software-installation, utorrent

I found the commands to install µTorrent in a post on this website.

When I run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/local/bin/utserver
```

It says:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/utserver’: File exists
```

What to do?

Comment: already `utserver` file was there in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Does that mean I don't need to run that command?

Comment: yes,skip to the next step

Answer (score 0):

I looked at that thread and it seems like you have the command for that step incorrect.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
```

instead of

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/local/bin/utserver
```

If all else fails I would recommend using one of the utorrent-like programs on the Ubuntu store. For example, I use Transmission.

Comment: I successfully installed utorrent with that command. @aegis